# Appending additional selectors to a previously declared variable containing a DOM element

Tags: html, jquery, radio-button, jquery-selectors

I cannot for the life of me find a reference on this, yet it is seemingly a very awkward piece of code to beat. It may be due to the exact wording I was using to find a result, but as far as I can tell. This is impossible.

The question is simple, I have a radio DOM element and a variable set as a DOM element.

```
<fieldset class="my-little-radio">
    <input id="radio-1" class="radio-input" type="radio" name="mylittleradio" value="1">
    <label for="radio-1" class="radio-label">Radio 1</label>
    <input id="radio-2" class="radio-input" type="radio" name="mylittleradio" value="2">
    <label for="radio-2" class="radio-label">Radio 2</label>
</fieldset>


var domRadioInput = $('.my-little-radio input[type=radio]');
```

I then run some JS that essentially requires the checked status to be switched to a sibling radio input, the radio input I would like must have the value myNewValue.

```
domRadioInput + '[value="' + myNewValue + '"]' + .prop('checked', true);
```

I am aware the above is wrong, but do you know how it can be achieved?

**Specific question: How can a variable set as a DOM element be reused to check for attribute changes, such as the value?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a radio DOM element and a variable set as a DOM element.

What you have is a variable (`domRadioInput`) that refers to a jQuery object; that jQuery object has references to all of the DOM elements that matched the selector when you called `$()` (two elements, in your case).

> I then run some JS that essentially requires the checked status to be switched to a sibling radio input, the radio input I would like must have the value myNewValue.

I'm going to assume that `myNewValue` contains `"1"` or `"2"`. If so, you can use jQuery's [`filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) (which is **not** the same as the one on arrays) to get a new jQuery object with all of the elements from your previous one that match the new selector (presumably just the one will match), then set the `checked` prop on them:

```
domRadioInput.filter(`[value="${myNewValue}"]`).prop("checked", true);
```

More in [the jQuery API documentation](https://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: Sounds ideal! Are the backticks essential or are they ' but formatted wrong?

Comment: @JasonIsMyName - It's not a formatting error. :-) That's a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).  If you were doing this without a template literal, you'd use string concatenation: `domRadioInput.filter('[value="' + myNewValue + '"]').prop("checked", true);`

Comment: Chowder - Are you also able to answer this question: /questions/72395764